# Eclipse with Python - having difficult with python version being picked up for egg file creation

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, version

I am using CentOS with Python 2.6 (/usr/bin/python2.6) but I installed Python 2.7.8 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7).

The egg files (on running a script on eclipse get created /usr/bin/python2.6/.. for the wrong version. I want it to get created in /usr/local/bin/python2.7/..

```
[code] [Desktop]$ which python
alias python='python2.7'
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 [/code]
```

The site-packages are present in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

I have set the .bashrc file and PYTHONPATH to point to Python2.7 and checked output of  "python -v" and "which python" which seems correct.

Is there something else that I could be missing? I always keep getting this error saying `"no module named pkg_resources"` found as a result of all this.

Thanks Lafada:

yum install python-setuptools
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cStringIO.so: undefined symbol: PyCapsule_New

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

This clearly explains that there is some version issue/mix-up.. would you know about this?

Update:
I found something on stackoverflow which helped me on 2 packages but not the others. I see the following on my Python Interpreters.

[code]

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-5.4.1-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.6.egg
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/six-1.3.0-py2.6.egg
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packag`enter code here`es
/usr/lib64/python2.6
/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2
/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages 
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/webkit-1.0
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info
```

[/code]

I need the packages referencing py2.6 to refer to py2.7 and create egg files for 2.7.

Comment: I cant even tell what is messed up here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing an "make altinstall" helped me and following http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/ was helpful.

For those modules that were still using py2.6, I re-installed them with pip by using "pip-2.7".

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `python-setuptools`

```
apt-get install python-setuptools
```

This will install `pkg_resources` module

Hi Lafada:

I have responded to your comment by editing my question.